# SQL for MS Access how to pick random row from a table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, random

I'm trying to make a Query from my Table "Questions", this table has the following fields: id(auto number),  Question(text) ; Category(text), difficulty (number)

The query I'm trying to make must return one random row for every difficulty (1-5), for a given Category.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Questions ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Access says: "Undefined function 'NEWID' in expression."